# map pattern vector with string vector

Tags: r, tidyverse, stringr, purrr

I'd like to find the first occurrence of an element of a pattern vector in a string vector and get an output vector of these strings where non-matches should be assigned to `NA`. Additionally, I'd like to use a compact vectorized solution for this problem (preferably a tidyverse solution).

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
```

Example:

```
patterns1 <- c("101", "102", "103", "101")
patterns2 <- c("101", "102", "103", "999", "101")
strings <- c("101a", "101a", "a102a", "aa103a")
```

For `patterns1` this works because every element exists in `strings`:

```
map_chr(patterns1, function(x) detect(strings, str_detect, x))
# [1] "101a"   "a102a"  "aa103a" "101a"
```

But with `patterns2` `map_chr` gives an error:

```
map_chr(patterns2, function(x) detect(strings, str_detect, x))
# Error: Result 4 is not a length 1 atomic vector
```

because `detect` returns `NULL` if the detection fails. Or do you recommend to use a workaround with `map` instead of `map_chr` and transform `NULL` elements to `NA`?

```
map(patterns2, function(x) detect(strings, str_detect, x))
# [[1]]
# [1] "101a"
#
# [[2]]
# [1] "a102a"
#
# [[3]]
# [1] "aa103a"
#
# [[4]]
# NULL
#
# [[5]]
# [1] "101a"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a condition

```
map_chr(patterns2, ~ detect(strings, str_detect, .x) %>% 
                               if(length(.) > 0) . else NA)
#[1] "101a"   "a102a"  "aa103a" NA       "101a"
```

---

Or concatenate with `NA` and take the `first` value

```
map_chr(patterns2, ~ c(detect(strings, str_detect, .x), NA)[1])
#[1] "101a"   "a102a"  "aa103a" NA       "101a"
```